# Typo3 Slide element translation - not able to edit

Tags: sql, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

First at all, I am new to the *new* `TYPO3`. 
The sites version is `8.7.17` and the last version I really worked with was `6.2.x ...`

I m dreadfully sorry if it is just a simple thing!

The system and the page:
Website with 25 sites. Each top part of the site contains a slider.
Base language is German, the second language is English.

Each site contains a slider at the top of the page.
So u find a german slider element and the english copy.

Lately we d the issue, that an error occured, when trying to edit the slide img meta for the english version. 
I researched and found the problem in forge and on stack so no worries - 'the latest version of `TYPO3 8.7.x` should fix that' - answers to the questions one year ago.

So we updated our system to `8.7.17.`

When I now open the english copy of the slide, there is no longer the opportunity to edit the meta.

No edit button :

[image]

Thought, that I maybe should edit the german element and just switch the language.

German element :

[image]

But when I do and try to change the language, I can just `create NEW`. 
So .. let s do this.

Create NEW :

[image]

Unfortunately when I then try to open the slide element (no matter if german or english) I get an SQL error.

SQL error :

[image]

I researched the old issue, the new `create NEW` issue and even the SQL issue and had tons of information, not knowing what really is helpful.

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with SQL server, not TYPO3. Here is the solution for this.

**First approach:**

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Run above command with terminal and set SQL Mode. That's it!

**Second approach:**

- Open phpmyadmin & select localhost
- Click on menu Variables & scroll down for sql mode
- Click on edit button to change the values & remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY & click on save.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked for me.

From now on there is only an edit button for the english image, when I first create meta data for the image (seen in screenshot 3). Not really nice, but working.